# Json() giving undefined in list?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Input for the Json():

[image: InputData]

When programsDataResponse object is passed to Json(programsDataResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet), it gives output on UI.

[image: output]

How can i remove the "undefined" from the collection.

Comment: what is `programsDataResponse` object?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior (assuming `OperandSeprator` is `string[]`) - it outputs `["[", "]"]`

Comment: programsDataResponse is the object of a class with multiple properties e.g   public List<string> OperandSeprator { get; set; }

Comment: Can you post the javascript code in the view that is making the call/response?

Comment: IE showing output in right format but in chrome, format is different